# Android Coordinator layout causing problems in status bar and navigation bar

Tags: android

I just created a new project template and am seeing the following issues:

1. This is the new project with zero changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the main content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This puts the content behind the navigation bar however:

[image]

If I remove the app_bar_scrolling_view_behaviour, it sits on top of the navigation bar, but also on top of the toolbar, and anyway I need that behaviour for the scrolling interations with the toolbar AFAIK.

2. If I add the scroll flags to the toolbar:

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Now when I scroll up to get rid of the toolbar, it still can be seen in the status bar:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered in the past this problem, and I solved it by using [Insetter library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/insetter). It basically automatically adds insets on top and bottom based on status & navigation bars size.

In your code, you would add the id `root` at your `CoordinatorLayout` and then at Activity's `onCreate` you could do something like this (if you use binding, otherwise you can use the `applyInsetter` on any `ViewGroup`:

```
binding.root.applyInsetter {
        type(statusBars = true) {
            padding(left = false, top = true, right = false, bottom = false)
        }
        type(navigationBars = true) {
            padding(left = false, top = false, right = false, bottom = true)
        }
}
```